# Read access to /data/data/com.android.chrome/app_chrome/profile on a Nexus 10

Tags: chrome-for-android, profiles

How's this for a catch 22 - I would like to make a copy of the full folder structure starting at the path above. I have explored:

- Finding ways to move the app onto the internet data storage (SD card equivalent), *before realising that it would likely still leave the app data in the protected `/data` directory*
- Looking for ways to root the device, without wiping the storage, as I have read is possible for a few other mobile devices (Nexus 7 for one)
- "Temporary rooting" the device - This looks to be most promising, but I cannot find how to do this for the Nexus 10

In my desperation, have also tried to export the Chrome for Android history (least preferable solution), but:

- Chrome for Android provides no way of saving `chrome://history`
- The Google based sync is missing many pages, even whole days of pages, when viewing in Portable Chrome on the desktop
- The press-and-hold clicking of individual links on `chrome://history` page, would take too long.
- `chrome:history` doesn't display the full URL's, so the screenshots (Power + Volume down, concurrently) I took are only semi-useful

Then there is the open tabs:

- `chrome:sessions`, `chrome:tasks` present a "Web page not found" error, which I presume means that they are not available on the Android version.

Does **anyone** have something else for me to try??

**EDIT:**

After [Dan Hulme's](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/12442) [pointing out](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/53995/read-access-to-data-data-com-android-chrome-app-chrome-profile-on-a-nexus-10#comment72442_53995) that there is already a [workaround to this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices), I would like to change this question to ask if there is any way to mount the back file `adb backup` produces, instead of having to recover it to a like device, in order to work with the files contained with the archive.

Comment: Thanks @DanHulme! Wish I saw that answer nearer to the start of the day :( I have edited this question to then be about possibilities to mount the `adb backup` backup, to view, instead of having to have a device to recover to, to view.

Comment: Don't bother saying you'd "like to change" the question. Just change it! Unlike a web forum, this site saves the revision history of your post, so you should just change the question to be the question you want, instead of tacking an "EDIT" message on the end.

Comment: Don't make it a chameleon question, though. If it's a new question, ask a new question.

Comment: @DanHulme / AlEverett - Happy to write up a new question, but personally I would prefer to keep this question, in it's original form (removing most of the **EDIT** I added), available to the community, so that steps I tried/someone looking to do the same thing (that might also not find the link to the workaround) can be helped by it. Suggestions on how you think I should accomplish this? As an aside - Forums do have one advantage (i.m.o) over this format, in that there is a clearer chain of what sorted each separate issue, from problem to solution.